# need advice with making a name generator in java

Tags: java

Hi, I'm trying to make a Star Wars name Generator and I am stuck. I am suppose to make the program follow these guidelines:

I should make a method called `promptstring`.

The user's Star Wars name is composed of a first and last name: 
For the first name, use the first 3 characters of the user's real first name, concatenated with the first 2 characters of the user's real last name.
For the last name, use the first 2 characters of the user's mother's maiden name, concatenated with the first 3 characters of the user's city of birth.
For the user's Star Wars planet, use the last 2 characters of the user's last name, concatenated with the user's car.

Example:

- Enter your first name: Thom
- Enter your last name: Yorke
- Enter your mother's maiden name: Selway
- Enter the city where you were born: Wellingborough
- Enter the first car your drove: Audi
- You are THOYO SEWEL of KEAUDI

Right now I'm just having compiler errors which are

> 8 errors found: File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 15]
>   Error: input cannot be resolved
>
> File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 18] Error: The method
>   nextLine() in the type java.util.Scanner is not applicable for the
>   arguments (int, int)
>
> File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 19] Error: last1
>   cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 19] Error: end cannot
>   be resolved to a variable
>
> File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 22] Error: The method
>   nextLine() in the type java.util.Scanner is not applicable for the
>   arguments (int, int)
>
> File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 25] Error: The method
>   nextLine() in the type java.util.Scanner is not applicable for the
>   arguments (int, int)
>
> File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 31] Error:
>   Starwarsname cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> File: J:\CS Projects\NameGenerator.java  [line: 34] Error:
>   Starwarsname cannot be resolved to a variable

I have reworked this program over and over again and I am stuck. Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.*;


 public class NameGenerator {
     static Scanner wars = new Scanner(System.in);

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         //Prompt for User's Name
         String first,last,mother,city,car;


         System.out.printf("Please state your First Name");
         first= wars.Line(0,2);

         System.out.printf("Please state your Last name");
         last=wars.nextLine(0,1);
         last1=wars.nextLine(-1,end);

         System.out.printf("Please state your mothers maiden name");
         mother=wars.nextLine(0,1);

         System.out.printf("Please state the city you were born in ");
         city=wars.nextLine(0,2);

         System.out.printf("Please state your first car");
         car=wars.nextLine();


         Starwarsname=first+last + mother + city  + "of" + last + car ;

         System.out.println("In a galaxy far, far away you are known as " + Starwarsname + "        MAY THE FORCE be with you!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you done any research into these errors before posting here? Most of them are pretty straightforward and a little research will probably give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the scanner incorrectly. It should be like this:

```
first = wars.nextLine();
```

If you want only the first two characters of first, then:

```
first = first.substring(0,2);
```

Same with the rest of your strings. You can't get a substring from using the scanner class. Scanner class only scans your input. Use the String.substring method (show above) to get the substring.

Edit: Also, you're trying to use a few variables that are undeclared. Make sure you declare the variable "Starwarsname" as String first before assigning it to something.

Answer (score 1):

The change the statements having

```
wars.nextLine(0,1);
```

to

```
wars.nextLine();
```

Later use

```
str.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)
```

method of String to get whatever part of the entered string you want,concatenate and print them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: end cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Indicates that you never declared the variable `end`. Make sure to have a line that is something like `String end;` before you use every variable.

```
Error: The method nextLine() in the type java.util.Scanner is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)
```

Indicates that `nextLine()` cannot take any parameters (see the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)). If you want to get a substring from the input, do something like `wars.nextLine().substring(0,2)`. Additionally, both numbers must be positive (the -1 in your code will cause an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code and test it...
i did the testing also.

points of concern:

- You did not declare some variables
- you did not check method names in the Scanner API. please check java
  doc for that.

please check and tell

```
import java.util.*;

public class NameGenerator {
    static Scanner wars = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //Prompt for User's Name
        String first, last, mother, city, car,Starwarsname,last1;
        int end=0;


        System.out.printf("Please state your First Name");
        first = wars.nextLine();//wars.Line(0, 2);

        System.out.printf("Please state your Last name");
        last = wars.nextLine();
//        last1 = wars.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Please state your mothers maiden name");
        mother = wars.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Please state the city you were born in ");
        city = wars.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Please state your first car");
        car = wars.nextLine();

        Starwarsname = first +" "+ last +" "+ mother +" "+ city + " of " + last +" "+ car;
        System.out.println("In a galaxy far, far away you are known as " + Starwarsname +
                           "        MAY THE FORCE be with you!");
    }
}
```

Comment: after commenting out last1 and int end = 0 it complies and runs that last part of the program should be more or less easy to do thank you very much for the assistance